# Pow implementation for double

Tags: c, floating-point, direct3d, ogre3d, fpu

I am developing a code that will be used for motion control and I am having a issue with the pow function.
I am using VS2010 as IDE.

Here is my issue:
I have:

```
    double p = 100.0000;
    double d = 1000.0000;
    t1 = pow((p/(8.0000*d),1.00/4.000);
```

When evaluating this last function, I don't get the better approximation as result. I am getting a 7 decimal digits correct, and the consequent digits are all trash.
I am guessing that pow function only casts any input variable as float and proceds with calculation.

1. Am I right?
2. If so, is there any code I can get "inspired" with to reimplement pow for a better precision?

Edit: Solved.

After all, I was having problems with FPU config bits, caused by Direct3D which was being used by OGRE 3D framework.

If using OGRE, on the config GUI, just set "Floating-point mode=Consistent".

If using raw Direct3D, when calling CreateDevice, make sure to pass "D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE" flag to it.

Original post:

> You may be using a libray that is changing the default precision of
>   the FPU to single-precision. Then all floating-point operations, even
>   on doubles, will actually be performed as single-precision operations.
>
> As a test, you can try calling _controlfp( _CW_DEFAULT, 0xfffff );
>   (you need to include ) before performing the calculation to
>   see if you get the correct result. This will reset the floating-point
>   control word to default values. Note that it will reset other settings
>   as well, which may cause issues.
>
> One common library that changes the floating-point precision is
>   Direct3D 9 (and maybe other versions too): By default, it changes the
>   FPU to single-precision when creating a device. If you use it, specify
>   the flag D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE when creating the device to prevent it
>   from changing the FPU precision.

Comment: see the prototype of `pow()` in the standard library comes with your compiler. glibc's `pow()` has a prototype with all `double`. The `float` version is called `powf()`.

Comment: C99 has the `long double` type for extra precision, but apparantly [Microsoft decided to get rid that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cx8xs15.aspx). MS C++ does have `pow` for `long double` arguments.

Comment: gcc produced this with "50 digits" precision 0.33437015248821100321663379872916266322135925292969

Comment: I did... I am using in deed double pow(double, double)... But, I mean, don't you find it very wierd that the function returns exactly 7 decimal digits precise results, the exact number of decimal digits that float type can bear?

Comment: Excel gives (1/80)^(1/4) == 0.334370152488211, in agreement with both what Aftnix got with gcc and what I got using VS2005. Also, your example doesn't paste well: prefix `t1` with double and fix the unbalanced parenthesis.

Comment: Are you using DirectX in your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be using a libray that is changing the default precision of the FPU to single-precision. Then all floating-point operations, even on `double`s, will actually be performed as single-precision operations.

As a test, you can try calling `_controlfp( _CW_DEFAULT, 0xfffff );`  (you need to include `<float.h>`) before performing the calculation to see if you get the correct result. This will reset the floating-point control word to default values. Note that it will reset other settings as well, which may cause issues.

One common library that changes the floating-point precision is Direct3D 9 (and maybe other versions too): By default, it changes the FPU to single-precision when creating a device. If you use it, specify the flag `D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE` when creating the device to prevent it from changing the FPU precision.

Comment: Interjay: Thank you sooooo much! I am using D3D and finally got rid of this terrible problem!

Comment: Other thing: I am using OGRE 3D for rendering. I thought of reading FPU status, changing it, then, afterr calculations, change it back. But this might not be thread safe, since cpu may be preempted before changing it back. What is the way to go: trying to do it through OGRE or trying some critical section thingy?
Thank you so much, again and again!

Comment: Ok, just made it through configuration GUI of direct3d rendering system. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

How did you determine you're only getting 7 digits of precision? Are you printing `t1` and specifying the correct output format? On my machine, with VS2010, the following code:

```
int main()
{
    double p = 100.0000;
    double d = 1000.0000;
    double t1 = pow(p/(8.0000*d),1.00/4.000);

    printf("t1=%.15f\n", t1); // C
    std::cout << "t1=" << std::setprecision(15) << t1 << '\n'; // C++
}
```

Produces this output:

```
t1=0.334370152488211
t1=0.334370152488211
```

Comment: I could identify it by analysing the result. I was getting 7 digits right, the other digits all diverged from the expected results. I solved this by using interjay's hint.