# double addition result being rounded

Tags: c#

I have some code that is behaving strangely and seems to be rounding the result of the addition of two **double** values. This is causing issues with my code.

Unfortunately I cannot fix this issue because my unit testing environment is working OK (not rounding) and my application is not OK (rounding).

In my test environment:

```
a = -3.7468700408935547
b = 525218.0
c = b + a
c = 525214.25312995911
```

Inside my application:

```
a = -3.7468700408935547
b = 525218.0
c = b + a
c = 525214.25
```

What can be causing this? Project config? (I'm using visual studio, btw)

**Edit (from comments)**
I'm stepping through the same code using the Visual Studio debugger, so it's the exact same piece of code.

I have more code but I narrowed the problem down to that particular sum.

The binary representations of each value are:

test environment:

```
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(a))   "00-00-00-00-97-F9-0D-C0"   string
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(b))   "00-00-00-00-44-07-20-41"   string
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(c))   "00-40-9A-81-3C-07-20-41"   string
```

inside application:

```
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(a))   "00-00-00-00-97-F9-0D-C0"   string
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(b))   "00-00-00-00-44-07-20-41"   string
System.BitConverter.ToString(System.BitConverter.GetBytes(c))   "00-00-00-80-3C-07-20-41"   string
```

**Edit 2:**

As [Alexei Levenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143594/double-addition-result-being-rounded#comment17878348_13143594) points out, this issue is caused by a library that changes the FPU config.

<sub>For anyone who is curious what this meant for me:
I was able to mitigate this issue for my particular piece of code, by making some assumptions about my input values and doing some preemptive values rounding which in turn made my calculations consistent.</sub>

Comment: How do you know the actual value is being rounded, and not just its display?

Comment: You have some code to "share"?

Comment: What are the variables defined as? It is likely `b + a` is getting rounded to 2DP due to variable choice...

Comment: Not every value can be accurately represented in binary, much like `1/3 = 0.333333333; 0.333333333 * = 0.99999999` in decimal, but then for different values.

Comment: It's almost as if the sum is being done with floats :/

Comment: @JonB Binary representation included.

Comment: @lboshuizen it's the same code being stepped, one at application runtime and other from a breakpoint in nunit.

Comment: @Killercam all the variables are doubles, at first I had some floats mixed with the doubles but then I changed the code to convert to doubles before doing anything else (just to be sure It wasn't the mix between floats and doubles).

Comment: Does you application do something strange with configuration of FPU? (like using some random library for math which reconfigures precision...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov now that you mention it, it might be the 3D engine I'm using.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov My 3D library uses Direct3D, which seems to be a [common cause for these issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524536/pow-implementation-for-double). Do you want to make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application may be doing something strange with configuration of FPU. I.e. using some random library for math which reconfigures precision...

Direct3d is possible suspect, see for example [Pow implementation for double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524536/pow-implementation-for-double).

Answer (score 1):

Use decimal if one wants preciscion such as needed in financial calculations.

**Edit** 
See:

- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [Five Tips for Floating Point Programming](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29637/Five-Tips-for-Floating-Point-Programming)

Comment: I thought of that, but i really need the speed provided by these data types, the only problem is that I cannot understand the difference between the environments to make the code work at all times.

Comment: @JoãoPortela the lack of precision is why doubles are used as such and that is the trade off you face.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I can never be sure if my fix is correct if I don't know what the problem is in the first place. That's what this question was for: understanding the problem.

Comment: I didn't know your second link. Thanks for that.

Comment: Wow. I'm learning C#/VS and my background comes from PHP where data types is not a huge issue. It blows my mind that 'Double' is screwing with my data and I [have] to use 'Decimal'...